# ckeditor-rails and paperclip not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, ckeditor, paperclip

I'm using CKEditor-rails (https://github.com/tsechingho/ckeditor-rails) and I'm having some issues with uploading images.  The model for uploading photos looks like this:

```
class Ckeditor::Picture < Ckeditor::Asset
  has_attached_file :data,
                    :styles => { :content => '800>', :thumb => '118x100#' },
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    :bucket => "********"

  validates_attachment_size :data, :less_than => 2.megabytes
  validates_attachment_presence :data

  def url_content
    url(:content)
  end
end
```

When I upload images using CKEditor, the URL of the image is a path with the format of "/system//pictures/data/000/000/016/content/**.jpg".

It doesn't appear the images are even being uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I used this setting in my model, try this.

```
has_attached_file :logo, :styles => { :orig => "300x400>",
                        :thumb => {:geometry => "80x58#", :format => :png},
                        :full => {:geometry => "#{SEARCH_IMAGE_WIDTH}x#{SEARCH_IMAGE_HEIGHT}#", :format => :png, :jcrop => true},
                        :cropped => {:geometry => "#{LOGO_WIDTH}x#{LOGO_HEIGHT}>", :jcrop => true, :format => :png} },
                        :storage => :s3,
                        :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root.to_s}/config/s3.yml",
                        :path => "logos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
                        :bucket => "photo/#{Rails.env}/system"
```